# Tensorflow Implement Multivariate Student T diagonal distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm implementing a diagonal multivariate student t distribution (so logP(x1,x2,x3,..xD) = logP(x1) + logP(x2)+ ....+ logP(xD) ) such that it can be used as base distribution for bijectors in TensorFlow

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

D = 2 # number of dimension
df = 5. # degree of freedom

# construct D univariate student t distribution

base_dist = tfd.StudentT(loc=tf.constant([0.] * D,dtype=DTYPE),
                         scale = tf.constant([1.] * D,dtype=DTYPE),
                         df = tf.constant([df],dtype=DTYPE))

Q = tfd.TransformedDistribution(distribution=base_dist,bijector=Chain)
# where Chain is a tfb.Chain() object that a sequence of bisector numbers
```

I change `tfd.StudentT.log_prob()` such that it sum over last axes. It takes shape `[batch_size,dim]` as input and return pdf with shape`[batch_size,]`

However, when I call `Q.log_prob(x)`; I got error `ValueError: event_ndims (0) must be larger than min_event_ndims (1)`

I'm not sure how to fix this error; can some one helps me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow Probability provides a way to create vector-valued distributions from scalar distributions via the [tfd.Independent](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Independent) meta-distribution. That would automatically perform the summation in `log_prob` that you want.

If you really wanted to implement things yourself, the issue you're having sounds like you didn't override the `event_shape` and `event_shape_tensor` methods (along with the `batch_shape` and `batch_shape_tensor`).

Lastly, typically when people talk about the multivariate student t distribution, they mean the elliptical distribution described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution), which is *not* the same thing as taking a product of 1D Student-t's distributions and then linearly transforming them. Recently, TFP added an implementation of the elliptical variant of this distribution [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MultivariateStudentTLinearOperator). It takes an affine transformation as input that you can use to setup the location/correlation structure of the distribution.